# What's the fastest way to get the Constructor of an Object in AS3?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, optimization, constructor

Which of these 3 is the fastest (least CPU cycles) on the AVM2 in ActionScript 3?

1. `Object(instance).constructor`
2. `(instance as Object).constructor`
3. `instance["constructor"]`

I would do some tests, but I have no idea how to accurately profile that kind of thing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––
performancetests.Constructors (5 iterations, 5,000,000 loops through each)                            
Player version: MAC 10,0,32,18 (debug)
––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––
method...................................................ttl ms...avg ms
instanceAsObjectConstructor                                9516  1903.20
instanceBracketConstructor                                 6941  1388.20
objectDotConstructor                                       9916  1983.20
––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––
```

I used [Grant Skinner's AS3 Performance test harness](http://www.gskinner.com/blog/archives/2009/04/as3_performance.html) and got these results.

Comment: This must be because the instanceBracketConstructor is the only one that doesn't cast the instance. Otherwise this result would scare me.